# How do I reconnect my Amazon RDS database to my EC2 instance after restarting?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm running a staging site through an EC2 instance which I stopped earlier tonight, without being aware that Amazon would give me a new IP address.

I've already edited all my database info in my site files with the new IP info and pushed them live. I'm certain that everything is correct. The site is showing up at the proper IP address too.

But I'm getting a "Unable to connect to database server. Please refresh in a few seconds." This would make me think that the database credentials were wrong, but I've double and triple checked them, and it turns out that the old database credentials are not working when I input them into Adminer (v4.3.1 in case it's important). It's like the database itself simply disappeared when I reset the server.

I happen to have a backup copy of the database on my laptop, so I can restore a new one in case AWS did somehow manage to delete it.

Can anyone clue me into what might be going on and how I might fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Is the MySQL server on the instance? Is the process running? Are you able to connect to it on `localhost` via SSH?

Comment: I can get on the server just fine using SSH. When I SSH onto the EC2 server and type: "service mysql status", I get "mysql: unrecognized service", but "rpm -qa | grep mysql" get me the expected results, and trying "yum install mysql mysql-server" tells me that SQL is already installed and working. Is any of that pertinent to what you were asking? Any idea how I check to see if the MySQL server is on this particular EC2 instance?

Comment: I got it! Thanks. The solution was simply to start MySQL again with: sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start. Wouldn't have ever found that in Google if it wasn't for your comment. =)

Comment: Please answer your own question - I think you have to wait 24 hours. Couple of tips - use an elastic IP address if you want a static IP. Stopping an EC2 instance with EBS storage doesn't change what's on the disk, so anything that happens is a problem with the configuration not AWS.

Comment: @MarvinLazer the question and comments do not match its title.  There is no evidence of Amazon RDS being used, here.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out! Answer was to start MySQL again using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```